# JSON response is bloated for API requests to Google Sheets

Tags: json, google-sheets-api

I'm using the spreadsheet JSON api on a public read-only document. Is there a way to not receive the links of the individual cells and all the extra bloat? I just want the data.

My request is constructed as

> `http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/DOCKEY/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=callback`

Eliminating the category and link objects would vastly shrink the response..

I could use basic instead of values, but then I would have to parse the content.$t. to get the values....

Is there another way I'm not finding?

Thanks.

Comment: I will need the entire sheet, which will ultimately be upwards of 7000 rows.

Comment: @claudio I don't suppose there's a way to make a single request to retrieve all sheets within a workbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using Apps Script, which will provide you with methods to retrieve the values of the cell range you specify:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#getValues

Comment: hmm. that might work if I had write access to, or interaction with the provider of said doc. It looks like you are able to add a script to the spreadsheet, triggering it via the ajax request. Would the resultant array then be able to be returned as a json-in-script to the client browser?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider downloading the spreadsheet in csv format.  There does not seem to be an API for that, but maybe you could build the URL yourself.

See also [Using the google drive API to download a spreadsheet in csv format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619805/using-the-google-drive-api-to-download-a-spreadsheet-in-csv-format)

Comment: the data is being consumed client-side by a web app; I suppose, ideally, that there should be an option for 'read-only' where it doesn't provide you all the editing references....

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the Apps Script [`SpreadsheetApp#Range#getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues) is the Sheets REST API's [`spreadsheets.values()`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values) endpoint. The benefit here is that you can deploy this from a location of your choosing, and are not confined to working in the Apps Script version of Javascript. Client libraries which simplify the implementation of authorized access are available from Google in a number of languages.

Additionally, when making requests to Google REST APIs, one of the [Standard Parameters](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/query-parameters) is the `fields` specification, which allows limiting the data that should be returned to only that which you request be sent.

To quote their partial response snippet:

> Spreadsheets are big, and often you don't need every part of the spreadsheet. You can limit what's returned in a Google Sheets API response, using the fields URL parameter. This is especially useful in the spreadsheets.get method. For best performance, explicitly list only the fields you need in the reply. The format of the fields parameter is the same as the JSON encoding of a FieldMask. In a nutshell, multiple different fields are comma separated, and subfields are dot-separated. For convenience, multiple subfields from the same type can be listed within parentheses.
>
> For example, to retrieve the spreadsheet's title, the sheet's properties, and the value and format of range A1:C10. you could use the following request:
>
> `GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/YOURSHEETID?ranges=A1:C10&fields=properties.title,sheets(sheetProperties,data.rowData.values(effectiveValue,effectiveFormat))`