# How can i download Current Spreadsheet using google script without having any manual intervention?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have to download current Active Spreadsheet to my local drive using google script.
Any script example to show how can I accomplish the same? I am able to get the file download URL in html pop up but that's not the goal what I want is download happens automatically and file is save to machine local drive.

Comment: Try posting some code showing what you have already attempted. You are more likely to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be using the [downloadAsFile(filename)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output#downloadasfilefilename) method to save the spreadsheet to your local machine.

You can check the code implementation in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644554/how-to-download-export-sheets-in-spreadheet-via-google-apps-script) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281272/initiate-a-download-from-google-apps-script).