# Convert automatically Google Sheets docs to .txt tabular text file

Tags: google-sheets, type-conversion, lotus-notes

I want to import Google-SpreadSheet data to lotus notes but not do no support the import from .gsheet filo so i want to automatically convert .gsheet doc to .txt file and after that import it using LotusNotes Script to create a doc with informations contained in that doc.

I must have to start form a .gsheet file.

Which are my options?
Can i use windows scipt ?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is, to get the csv from the spreadsheet. Accoring to responses to [this post in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619805/using-the-google-drive-api-to-download-a-spreadsheet-in-csv-format) this is simply a matter of using the right url.

As soon as you have the url you can use LotusScript- Functions to call that URL and import the csv- data to your documents / database.

Just google for the right starting point (e.g. "lotusscript read web site") and come back if you have concrete questions in your created script.

Comment: File>Publish to the web will give you csv and tsv options straight to a URL.