# The new google sheets API broke downloading from drive. Now, how should one download an entire sheet?

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I used to use this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12507856/3772221

Where I would send a fetch to a URL in this form, replacing `${gid}` and `${id}` with the id and and gid of the sheet.

```js
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${id}/export?format=csv&gid=${gid}
```

but as of today it's no longer working for me. After I went looking online for the reason, I saw that google updated their spreadsheet API yesterday.

The only thing that I've found now on downloading a specific worksheet from a spreadsheet is this: https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get#http-request, but this page is pretty unhelpful considering that I don't want a value range. I just want want to download the file as a csv as if I clicked the download link.

Does anyone know a method similar to what I was using before? I don't want to use this new API, but rather download the file itself as I was doing before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new URL that worked for me is in the form:

```js
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/${id}/export?format=csv&id=${id}&gid=${gid}
```