# Creating a link to download whole spreadsheet from Google Drive

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I want to create download link for my spreadsheet on google drive and I read about something like that:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/MY_SPREADSHEET/export?format=csv
```

But it only downloads first sheet. I've read about `GID` parameter, but I don't want to spend time developing something that will get all GID's from API, and then download every sheet. Is there any way to have one link that leads to download of whole spreadsheet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to try suggestion in [Labnol's guide](http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/):

> Open your Google Spreadsheet in the browser, make the sheet Public (or Anyone with a link) and make a note of the shared URL. It should be something like this:
>
> `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILE_ID/edit?usp=sharing`
>
> The direct download links use a similar format as Google Documents and will read like:
>
> `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILE_ID/export?format=xlsx`
> `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILE_ID/export?format=pdf`

In addition to that, you may want to also try using the suggested URL in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323312/the-new-google-sheets-api-broke-downloading-from-drive-now-how-should-one-down?noredirect=1&lq=1) and see if it will help.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/${id}/export?format=csv&id=${id}&gid=${gid}
```

Comment: Thanks. I see that when downloading `formar=csv`, then it downloads only first sheet, but when using xlsx, then it downloads whole spreadsheet. That's what I wanted.

Comment: Did t his stop working in 2022?