# Is there a way to download data from a public link to google colab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am currently working with a Jupyter file on google colab with 5000 images and several csv files. I wish to find a way to download these data into the colab from a shareable link from google drive without mount to drive, which is: I upload these data into drive first and make them "anyone can view with link", and then I wish to find a way to download these data into colab with this link (So that others can simply run my code without authorization or mount to drive)

Is there any way I can achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: The answer from s.abbaasi in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60739653/gdown-is-giving-permission-error-for-particular-file-although-it-is-opening-up-f) worked for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `gdown`.

For example, an image url

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ztBz3C_2BlXgNGK2mbarGnVqoI287_XT/view?usp=sharing
```

It's id = 1ztBz3C_2BlXgNGK2mbarGnVqoI287_XT

So, you can download it with

```
!gdown 1ztBz3C_2BlXgNGK2mbarGnVqoI287_XT
```

Comment: Thanks! How do you do it for a folder?

Comment: @AmanBagrecha try to copy folder from drive to `content` and zip it. Then you can download it. for example there is a folder named `test`:
`
`!cp -r /content/drive/MyDrive/FERET ./`
`!zip -r 'test.zip' 'test'`

Comment: gdown works! I zipped the folder and then stored it on google drive. Then I downloaded the zipped folder using gdown onto google colab and unzipped there.

Answer (score 7):

you can use `!wget` in colab to download .csv file in your runtime storage
For Example
this is public link for google sheet
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILE_ID/edit?usp=sharing`

we need to get download url for this google sheet file
follow link to get download link

[Creating a link to download whole spreadsheet from Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062855/creating-a-link-to-download-whole-spreadsheet-from-google-drive)

now we got download url in this form
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILE_ID/export?`

type this code in colab
`!wget https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILE_ID/export?`
file will be downloaded like this
[snap shot from colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjHn5.png)

rename file as your choice
[rename snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpPAE.png)

finally import it using
`df = pd.read_csv("/content/file.csv")`

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `!wget`.

Example:

```
!wget 'http://socia-lab.di.ubi.pt/~hugomcp/dataset.tar'
```

If you want to download it to a given directory, you can go to that directory and execute the command.

Example:

```
%cd FRCNN/folder1/folder2
```

then

```
!wget 'download link'
```