# Download File in Appmaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I have created one app in Appmaker, I want to download certain reports from the Drive tables in Appmaker. For this currently I am creating SpreadSheet using Drive APIs. I want to add download feature as well which allows users to Download Spreadsheet in their local machine.

I have done research on Appscript which allows users to Download files using ContentService, however I do not have any HTMl page from where I can invoke this method. Are there any alternatives for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can get download URL using [DriveApp Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) service

```javascript
// Server script
var downloadUrl = DriveApp.getFileById(FileIdGoesHere).getDownloadUrl();
```

Comment: I am getting `null` value in `downloadUrl` .

Comment: Are you getting `null` for all files types? I think it is expected behavior for files that are not actually files. Spreadsheets for example. If you go to `File -> Download` in spreadsheet it will offer to you to select export file format (xlsx, pdf, csv, etc...). So, most likely you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619805/ or for https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents (aka https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)