# Download function in Google AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

[From answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50030748/9426876), how did actually we use the download URL to actually download the file when a button is clicked? Does AppMaker have any built-in function for download? Thanks ..

Comment: You need to display this as a clickable link to end users. Once they click on this it will download the file

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using [Link Widget](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/widgets#Link)

[image: Add link]